# Subject GRE exam 9768 Q.18

Tags: limits, gre-exam

The question is given in the following picture:

[image]

My first answer to the question was A. My justification was as follows:
$A(r) = \pi - \pi r^2$ and \begin{equation*}
\lim_{ r \rightarrow 1^-}
\frac{A(r)}{a(r)}= \lim_{ r \rightarrow 1^-}\frac{\pi - \pi r^2}{a(r)}
\end{equation*}

And I substituted for $ r = 1$ in the numerator, so the numerator becomes 0, and this is for any value of the denominator then the answer is A as I choose.

But the right answer is E, so I remember that the area of the circle with center O contracts, but why we should know that when $r=1$ the area of the circle with center O should be 0, could anyone explain this for me?

Comment: The numerator may be $0$ when $r = 1$.  You said "this is true for any denominator", but actually if you're going to set $r = 1$ in the numerator, the you *have* to do it in the denominator as well.  You can't selectively choose to just evaluate $r = 1$ in the numerator and leave $r$ as a variable in the denominator.  Also, hopefully it's clear that at $a(1) = 0$.  So that means you get $\frac{0}{0}$ at $r = 1$, so the expression is undefined at $r = 1$.  So you'll have to do something else to find the limit other than substituting $r = 1$ in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When evaluating limits you need to be more careful. Consider:

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{ x \rightarrow 0}
\frac{x}{x}= 1
\end{equation*}

Although the numerator evaluates to 0 when $x = 0$ it should be clear that the limit isn't 0.

You should show that $a(r) = \pi(1-r)^2$. Then your limit becomes:

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{ r \rightarrow 1^-}
\frac{A(r)}{a(r)}= \lim_{ r \rightarrow 1^-}\frac{\pi - \pi r^2}{\pi(1-r)^2} = \lim_{ r \rightarrow 1^-}\frac{1 - r^2}{(1-r)^2}
\end{equation*}

Can you do some algebra to simplify this?

Comment: @Intuition it may help your intuition to note that with $0<r<1$ that $1-r^2$ is always bigger than $(1-r)^2$ and the relative difference between the two increases as $r\rightarrow 1^-$

Comment: yes I can, thank u very much Matt.

Comment: yeah thank u very much @Χpẘ